# Fast 3D texture mapping

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, texture

Is there a tool -- preferably free -- that can "paint" texture maps in a 3D view? (Similar to [Pixologic's Sculptris](http://pixologic.com/sculptris/))

I have several low-poly (<1000) models that I want to "touch up" the textures.  I've written a program that converts them to `.obj` including normals and texture coordinates.  So far everything shows correctly in **Wings3D** and **Blender**.

I'm just looking for something fast.

Comment: Blender has the capability to paint in a 3D view, not sure if you already knew that or not.

Comment: If you are not animating and looking for a final 3D design have you thought about exporting your work and importing it into Gimp and doing touch ups?  In the past Ive imported from 3DS Max into Photoshop and vice versa for details on low poly objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look like the software you mentioned is already free. [Pixologic Sculptris](http://pixologic.com/sculptris/)**

Have you already tried the download?

## Update:

Found a program called [UVMapper](http://www.uvmapper.com/index.html). It has a demo version you can download before you purchase it.

> **UVMapper Professional** is a stand-alone texture mapping utility for the
>   creation and modification of UV coordinates for n-sided polygonal 3D
>   models.  UVMapper Professional offers multiple, fully configurable
>   viewports with completely interactive 2D and 3D views.

Comment: Yes that's why I mentioned it.  On my system at least -- it needs some improvement.